# c++ boost message_queue, could 64bit binary send messages to 32bit binary

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, message-queue, 32bit-64bit

Hi I am trying to implement interprocess communication between 32/64 binaries by boost message_queue on linux

According to [64bit and 32bit process intercommunication boost::message_queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915142/64bit-and-32bit-process-intercommunication-boostmessage-queue/12516629#12516629), here is my implementation:

```
// sender.cc, x86_64
typedef boost::interprocess::message_queue_t<offset_ptr<void, int32_t, uint64_t>> Ipmq;
int main() {
    Ipmq mq(create_only, "mq", 100, sizeof(int32_t));
    int32_t i = 42;
    mq.send(&i, sizeof(int32_t), 0);
}
```

```cpp
// receiver.cc, x86
typedef boost::interprocess::message_queue_t<offset_ptr<void, int32_t, uint64_t>> Ipmq;
int main() {
    Ipmq mq(open_only, "mq");
    int32_t i;
    uint32_t rsize;
    uint32_t p;
    mq.receive(&i, sizeof(int32_t), rsize, p);
}
```

sender works while receiver throws:

> boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception what():
> boost::interprocess_exception::library_error

and aborts when calling `mq.receive(...)`.

Could you tell me if it is possible to ipc between 32/64 binaries using boost `message_queue` ?

If not, could you tell me any other ipc method on linux whose receiver can set a time out?

Thanks